# Ant Design Upload Component in react.js with Axios - Getting 404 Error in Console and Tooltip

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, axios, antd

I am using Ant Design's Upload component in my React app to allow users to upload images to the server. I am using the action and customRequest props to send the image file to the server using Axios, like so:

```
export default function ScanNow() {
  const [previewVisible, setPreviewVisible] = useState(false);
  const [previewImage, setPreviewImage] = useState("");
  const [previewTitle, setPreviewTitle] = useState("");
  const [fileList, setFileList] = useState([]);
  const [uploading, setUploading] = useState(false);
  const [uploadSuccess, setUploadingSuccess] = useState(false);
  const [uploadError, setUploadingError] = useState(false);

  const handleCancel = () => setPreviewVisible(false);

  const handlePreview = async (file) => {
    if (!file.url && !file.preview) {
      file.preview = await new Promise((resolve) => {
        const reader = new FileReader();
        reader.readAsDataURL(file.originFileObj);
        reader.onload = () => resolve(reader.result);
      });
      console.log(file);
    }
    setPreviewImage(file.url || file.preview);
    setPreviewTitle(
      file.name || file.url.substring(file.url.lastIndexOf("/") + 1)
    );
    setPreviewVisible(true);
  };

  const handleUpload = useMutation(async (formData) => {
    const config = {
      url: `${API_URL}/SendImage`,
      method: "post",
      data: formData,
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
      },
    };

    // Post request using axios library
    const response = await axios.post(`${API_URL}/SendImage`, formData, config);
    console.log(response.data);
    setUploading(false);
    setUploadingSuccess(true);
    setUploadingError(false);
    return response.data;
  });

  const handleChange = ({ fileList: newFileList }) => setFileList(newFileList);

  // Function to upload the image to the server
  const handleFileUpload = async () => {
    const formData = new FormData();

    fileList.forEach((file) => {
      formData.append("image", file.originFileObj);
    });

    setUploading(true);

    try {
      await handleUpload.mutateAsync(formData);
      setFileList([]);
    } catch (error) {
      setUploading(false);
      setUploadingError(true);
      console.log(error, "Something went wrong");
    }
  };

  const uploadButton = (
    <div>
      <PlusOutlined />
      <div>Upload</div>
    </div>
  );

  return (
    <>
      <div className="upload">
        <p className="upload__heading">Upload Images to Scan</p>
        <div className="upload__wrapper">
          {uploading ? (
            <p>Please wait, uploading images...</p>
          ) : uploadSuccess ? (
            <p>Images uploaded successfully!</p>
          ) : uploadError ? (
            <p>Error while uploading image!</p>
          ) : null}
          <Upload
            className="upload__file-container"
            listType="picture-card"
            accept="image/*"
            multiple={true}
            fileList={fileList}
            onPreview={handlePreview}
            onChange={handleChange}
          >
            {fileList.length >= 12 ? null : uploadButton}
          </Upload>
          {fileList.length === 0 ? (
            <Empty image={Empty.PRESENTED_IMAGE_SIMPLE} />
          ) : (
            <Modal
              className="upload__preview-modal"
              open={previewVisible}
              title={previewTitle}
              onCancel={handleCancel}
              footer={null}
            >
              <img
                className="upload__preview"
                alt="scan-image"
                src={previewImage}
              />
            </Modal>
          )}
          {fileList.length > 0 && (
            <div>
              <button
                className="upload__button"
                type="primary"
                icon={<UploadOutlined />}
                onClick={handleFileUpload}
              >
                Upload
              </button>
            </div>
          )}
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

The problem is that whenever I try to upload an image, I get a 404 error in the console and tooltip, even though the image is being successfully sent to the server and saved. I have checked my server-side code and it seems to be working fine. I also want to stop the default behaviour of the component to not upload directly upon selction of file, only upload when button gets clicked.

Can someone please help me figure out why I am getting this error and how I can fix it? Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Try this. Pass beforeUpload function to Upload component and return false. `beforeUpload={() => false}`

Comment: Thank you Muhammad. Passing the beforeUpload Function solved the issue.